# Apache https configurations

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I am trying to setup my domain name with a self signed cert. I created the cert and placed the `server.key` and `server.crt` files into `C:/apache/config/` Then I updated my `httpd.confg` host to include the following,

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:443>
    DocumentRoot C:/www
    ServerName example.com:443
    ServerAlias www.example.com:443

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile C:/apache/conf/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/apache/conf/server.key
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLProxyEngine off
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I go to https://example.com I get the following error.

> SSL connection error Unable to make a secure connection to the server.
>   This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
>   authentication certificate that you don't have. Error 107
>   (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

When I run curl https://example.com I get the error,

> curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Other configurations that might be conflicting

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   DocumentRoot C:/www/domain
</VirtualHost>

# <VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:443> ..Above config is here </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:80>
   ServerName subdomain.example.com
   ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com
   DocumentRoot C:/www/subdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have openssl installed?  Can you run something like `openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443` ?

Comment: didn't install openssl on the server, but i made the server.crt and server.key on my mac with openssl

Comment: Ah, good, you have a Mac.  Run the openssl command from your Mac, then. Actually, you have "curl" on the Mac.  (I thought you were using Windows, which doesn't have openssl, since you're using a Win server).

Comment: @cjc It gives me an unknown protocol error. I updated my question with the full error

Comment: OK, that error basically says that you're not making an SSL connection because the server is presenting as a plain HTTP server. You've reloaded Apache, right?  I see a couple config issues.  One is the ServerName and ServerAlias don't need the port number specification ":443".  Remove that.  But that's a different issue, and shouldn't affect this particular problem. I see the listen interface is a private IP address. Do you have mydomain.com set up in DNS correctly to go to 192.168.5.250?

Comment: Does `apachectl configtest` return OK?  I'm not sure how you'd run that in Windows.  Is mod_ssl installed?

Comment: @cjc I've updated my question with more config info. The ip is correct because it works for standard http. I have 2 routers in front of my modem so it a little weird.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2864/discussion-between-sissonb-and-cjc)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:443>
  ServerName example.com:443
  ServerAlias www.example.com:443
```

To:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
```

And change:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:80>
```

To:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Then reload apache and see if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my virtual host for `192.168.5.250:443` before my virtual host for `192.168.5.250:80`

So when  `NameVirtualHost` doesn't specify the port the order of the virtual hosts matters

Config that ignores port 443

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.5.250

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:80>
    # virtual host configs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:443>
    # virtual host configs
</VirtualHost>
```

Configs that work

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.5.250:80
NameVirtualHost 192.168.5.250:443

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:80>
    # virtual host configs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:443>
    # virtual host configs
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.5.250

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:443>
    # virtual host configs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.5.250:80>
    # virtual host configs
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And that worked?!

Comment: @cjc yep, I clarified the issue a bit more in my answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had not enabled the site 'default-ssl'. Only '000-default' was listed in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folder.

Enable SSL site on Ubuntu 14 LTS, Apache 2.4.7:

```
a2ensite default-ssl
service apache2 reload
```